# updating column when equi join returns multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query like this:

```
update TABLEA set x1 = b.x2, y1 = b.y2
from TABLEB b
where pid = b.id
```

however, ID is not unique in TABLEB and so can return 0, 1 or more rows. It seems to be working, and I'm not actually that bothered which row I get the data from as the x2/y2 values I want are always the same for the same ID.

Is the above ok and will it just update from one row, or should I be modifying the sql to ensure only one row is returned? For future reference, even if it is ok, what is the query to only return the first row it finds and is it just as efficient as the above?

thanks.

Comment: @LONG . . . Not at all.  `merge` was introduced to support the "upsert" command, where a single command is used for both updating and inserting.

Comment: Not sure about that. `update from` is not ANSI, iirc, but `merge` is.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, good to know that, thank you, Gordon :) I rarely use `merge` only when the non deterministic result appear xD

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but it is going to update using an indeterminate value.

If this concerns you, you can use `apply`:

```
update a
    set x1 = b.x2,
        y1 = b.y2
from tablea a cross apply
     (select top (1) b.*
      from tableb b
      where a.pid = b.id
     ) b
```

By putting an `order by` in the subquery, you can control which value gets updated.

Comment: thanks, is this just as efficient as the basic code I wrote? also, I've never come across cross apply before. I've heard of (but never used) partition over, are these similar things?

Comment: @NeilWalker . . . I believe this is more efficient, because the `update` will be only attempted at most once per row.